# Parse does not send notifications to all devices

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, push

My problem is that to send a general notification, some users do not receive the push notification. Other users on the other hand do receive this notice. Anyone has happened or know how to fix it?

Comment: Think of it like this. Presumably you have googled this question prior to posting and failed to find anything. This suggests that this is not a bug on Parse's end but rather yours. If only we had something to look at... to help you or even a bit more background would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to send out notifications on Parse, you should see this section at the top of the top of the **Send Push Notification** page. You might not be selecting **Everyone** when you send out your notification therefore it is only sent to a specific audience. If you want your notifications to be delivered to all users, then select **Everyone**. Also, make sure all users have the the newest version of your app. If you have installed the app on a device before you implemented Parse, those devices will not receive notifications. Only devices with the app that has Parse implemented will receive notifications.

[image]